# Como saber quantos caracteres tem depois da virgula c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria de contar quantos caracteres tem depois da virgula. Eu estava usando

```
public static string strToDouble(String text)
        {
            string aux;
            if (text.IndexOf(",00") <= 0)
            {
                aux = text + ",00";

                return aux;
            }
            return text;
        }
```

Mas ele so me retorna se esses caracteres estão na variavel.

Preciso saber se tem virgula e se sim quantos caracteres.

Comment: O que pretende fazer ao certo com o método `strToDouble()`? Pegar num número e se não tiver casas decimais adicionar duas?

Comment: Você precisa esclarecer melhor o que deseja, este método faz uma coisa, você agora quer que ele faça outra coisa? Ou quer outro método?

Comment: A ideia do metodo era pegar o numero caso nao tivesse casas decimais e adicionar sim.

Comment: Mas eu gostaria de um metodo para contar e eu poder adicionar de uma forma diferente

Comment: Por exemplo se o numero for 1,5 adiciona somente um zero 1,50 se for 1,06 não adiciona nenhum se for 1 adciona dois zeros 1,00

Comment: Vamos entender melhor o que deseja. O seu método tem um nome que parece querer transformar um texto para um número do tipo `double`?. Isto está correto? parece ser um problema XY, você quer outra coisa do que está pergunta. Diga o que precisa resolver para darmos a solução mais adequada, parece que o que está perguntando não é a solução para seu problema. Qual é o dado que você tem? É uma *string* sendo lida em algum lugar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
//String alvo
string palavra = "3,5888666454";
//Pega onde está a virgula
int virgulaIndice = palavra.IndexOf(',');
//Divide e pega apenas os chars[] depois da virgula
string restoDepoisDaVirgula = palavra.Substring(virgulaIndice);
//Conta todos esses chars[]
int tamanhoDepoisDaVirgula = restoDepoisDaVirgula.Length;           
//Tem que tirar uma casa, pois é a casa da própria virgula, queremos apenas as casas depois dela
tamanhoDepoisDaVirgula--;

//Esta pronto, agora é só usar a var tamanhoDepoisDaVirgula para saber a quantidade!
```

Answer (score -1):

Quebre sua string em um array com o split

```
var res = suaString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

A segunda posição do array vai conter a parte da string depois da vírgula

```
if (res.Count() > 1)
  var qrdt = res[1].Lenght;
```

Gabriel
https://desenvolvimentofullstack.wordpress.com